# Closing Settings dialog causes application to quit

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

So here's the setup. I have a standalone WPF application which I've built with VB. Contained in the application is two windows, `MainWindow` and `SettingsWindow`, which opens as a dialog and is called from a subprocedure in `MainWindow.xaml.vb` on the event of a clicked "Settings" button (I like working with code-behind much better than XAML if I can help it).

In `SettingsWindow.xaml.vb`, I have a subprocedure handling the event of clicking a close button in the window. It executes `Me.Close()`. The intent is to close `SettingsWindow` and return focus to `MainWindow`, but instead, the entire application terminates.

Additionally, clicking the close button in `MainWindow` closes `MainWindow`, but doesn't terminate the application in Visual Studio's debug mode, while closing `SettingsWindow` does.

When building the application and running it outside of Visual Studio (running the .exe itself in Windows), closing `SettingsWindow` returns to `MainWindow` as intended, but attempting to re-open `SettingsWindow` causes the entire application to crash.

I'm relatively new to Visual Studio, and I can post code as needed. Thanks ahead of time for the help.

First, here is my `Application.xaml.vb' file handling app startup:

```
Class Application

    Public Shared initmain As MainWindow = New MainWindow()

    Public Shared Sub AppStart() Handles Me.Startup
        initmain.UpdateSettings()
        initmain.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code above checks `My.Settings`, which works fine, then calls `MainWindow` open.

Here is the code in the `MainWindow` sub calling `SettingsWindow`:

```
Private Sub SettingStart() Handles SettingsButton.MouseUp
    Dim SettingWin As SettingsWindow = New SettingsWindow()

    ' "If" blocks here that check My.Settings before opening the window

    SettingWin.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Finally, here is the code that closes `SettingsWindow`:

```
Private Sub CloseButtonClick() Handles CloseButton.MouseUp
        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

If you need it, here is `Application.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Startup="AppStart">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Update:**

It looks like the issue has to do with the fact that the instance of `MainWindow` in `Application.xaml.vb` is `Public Shared`, but I need to be able to call to that instance from other places to update settings in realtime, so I can't change this. Workarounds?

Additionally, the program now functions properly outside of Visual Studio, no longer crashing.

Comment: We're not novel writers, we're programmers. We can't help you without seeing your code. Sometimes one line of code explains more than 5 paragraphs of text.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to SO. I posted my code, I hope it helps. Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: Is your `settingsWindow` set as the startup form for the project?

Comment: No, it isn't. In the `Application` class, a sub handling the `Startup` event creates a new instance of `MainWindow` and opens it. Then, a new instance of `SettingsWindow` is created from a sub within `MainWindow`. So, in theory, everything should return back to the `Application` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose" in Application.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose"         >
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub ButtonSetting_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonSetting.Click

        Dim SettingWin As SettingWindow = New SettingWindow()
        Dim rslt As Boolean = False

        rslt = SettingWin.ShowDialog()



    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. But thank you anyway, because you did lead me on the right track. I changed the `ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown` and called the `End` statement to terminate execution after I call a custom `UpdateSettings` procedure (used to save settings).